# Postman: ordering of fields in form-data request

Tags: postman

I have [a server set up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-upload-server) to which I can successfully send the following request:

```
curl localhost:8081/graphql   \
    -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { uploadFile(file: $file) { id } }", "variables": { "file": null } }'
    -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }'
    -F 0=@a.txt
```

However, if I paste that into Postman, or try to build the request manually, I get an error on the server-side stating

> Custom error:  Misordered multipart fields; files should follow “map” (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).

But in Postman, I have defined the fields in that order:

[image: postman field ordering]

Does Postman do anything on its own to re-order the fields? Is there anything I can do to control the order?

Update: Filed a bug with Postman here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4461

Comment: You can use different tools as JMeter

Comment: A bug in Postman. Insomnia works well.

Answer (score 2):

[image: postman config]

This way worked for me,instead of giving file name as "0" I gave "nfile" and order I maintained same operations,map and nfile

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your solution. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Have you tried that the GraphQL server (configured as linked in the OP) can also accept the file from this request?

Comment: @Agilanbu I will keep that in mind. Thank you this is my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Postman seems to order fields alphabetically so 0 would become the first field. I renamed my own file fields as "nfile1" etc.

But I found this question because I was able to read only the first file. And I'm not sure if it caused by the naming I'm using. But that way you can at least test with one file on Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Altair GraphQL Client](https://altair.sirmuel.design/) to test out your file upload implementation as explained [here](https://sirmuel.design/working-with-file-uploads-using-altair-graphql-d2f86dc8261f).